# Javascript to read downloaded files bypassing file input dialog

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am working with a web application which allows users to send files (images, different office documents) as attachments to their inquires.

Now I am stuck implementing the following feature of the application:
1. User opens his inquiry.
2. Downloads one of the files attached to it.
3. Say in case of an office document (docx file) the browser starts MS Word and opens this document.
4. User updates the document and saves it and closes MS Word.
5. User saves the updates of the inquiry and the file the user updated is supposed to be sent to the server so that the user would not need to open file input dialog to add it.

Steps from 1 to 4 work OK.

The document is fetched from the server as Base64 string, gets converted to blob and gets finally opened

```
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

var a: any = document.createElement("a");
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style = "display: none";
a.href = blobUrl;
a.download = "myAttachmentName.docx";
a.click();
```

The problem starts with Step 5. So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to find the file the browser saved the file `"myAttachmentName.docx"` to?
2. Is there a way to read from this file without user intervention, i.e. bypassing the need for the user to open file input dialog to find the file and attach it? The assumption is that even if the user has not modified the file it is not a problem to PUT and overwrite it on the server

Comment: JavaScript can not upload any file off the users machine without them selecting it.

Comment: No. Due to Web browser security restrictions, you cannot programmatically choose files to upload from a user's machine.

Comment: You may be able to accomplish something similar to this requirement with WebDAV or the Sharepoint protocol (for what I have read), but not just pure JS.